# Density and threshold based clustering in dbscan

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan, hdbscan

I am working on some thermal temperature data of industrial parts. I have a pixel-wise temperature of the part with temperature values. I want to use `dbscan` to identify parts that have clusters of pixels in each part where all points in the cluster exceed a threshold temperature. I have tried using `dbscan` but do not know how to identify using both threshold temperature and size of the cluster as conditions.

I have tried to isolate only points that cross the threshold(230) and try to see if that cluster exceeds a certain size. The code below:`c(1,3)` are the `x`,`y` values of the temperature and `v` is the temperature.

```
new<-sub%>%filter(sub$v>230)%>% as.data.frame(.)
db <- fpc::dbscan(new[,c(1,3)], eps =3, MinPts = 10)
plot(db, new[,c(1,3)], main = "DBSCAN", frame = FALSE)
```

complete part visual:
[image: complete part visual]

`dbscan` output after filtering using threshold temperature":

[image: dbscan output]

Comment: As a follow up, it would workout even if the filtered data of the part (>230) is checked to see if there is atleast one cluster with a minimum 10x10 pixel presence meeting the criteria (>230 C).

Answer (score 1):

Never use the `fpc` package. Use `dbscan` instead!

I'm not sure whether DBSCAN is the right tool for your taskz because below you talk about10x10 regions. For that, a standard *convolution* would be much more appropriate...

But other than that DBSCAN could work for you, provided that you choose attributes (n, m, f, c? What are alle these?) and parameters (radius  minpts) appropriately. Maybe your epsilon was just too small?

Comment: n, m, f, c are these parameters for dbscan or is it a question for me ?

Comment: That is a question for you. These are in your plots.

Comment: f is the row number and c is the column number: this was on a subset of data of the part above a specific threshold. n is the row and m is the column : this was a basic k means on the entire part.